# Somewhere vs. elsewhere

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between somewhere and elsewhere.

My understanding is:

> Somewhere-at a particular unknown place.
>
> Elsewhere-at some place.

They seem identical.

Answer (score 3):

- **somewhere** means an unknown or unspecified place
- **elsewhere** means not here or not in the place previously referred to

"I was looking for Susan and went to her house.  She wasn't there.  She had gone somewhere."  We don't know where.

"I was looking for Susan and went to her house.  She wasn't there.  **She was elsewhere**."  *Elsewhere* is anywhere but her house

More often than "elsewhere" you will see "somewhere else", with the same meaning.  "She wasn't there.  She was somewhere else."